# Can I use microwave turntable glass plate in convection mode?

Tags: microwave, convection, glass

I bought [a Singer SMW25GCQ6 model microwave oven](https://www.singersl.com/products/index.asp?pcode=SIN_SMW25GCQ6&PC=microwave_ovens). It has convection and grill features. For baking cakes and for grilling we don't use the glass turntable plate since we thought it could cause the cakes to brown unevenly.

Is it safe to use the glass turntable in convection mode with the baking to hold the baking cake containers? I'm asking this because there is mode which uses microwave + convection for roasting chicken. So that means the glass turntable should be there and it will work for convection mode as well right?

Then how about grill mode?

[image]

Comment: A quick search online has examples of m/w + convection units that either use the glass turntable with the conv. + grill or specify to not use it.  What does your owners' manual say?  Yours is really a question that should be answered by the manufacturer for that particular product.

Comment: Well manual comes with only minimal stuff. But there is a label on the glass turnable "Microwave Oven Only". I'm not sure whether it mean microwave mode only. If so how i'm i going to get the chicken roasted evenly on all sides :( ?

Comment: Sorry, GAP, I even tried hunting down information from Singer but had no luck with that.  Can you just manually turn your chicken a few times through the baking process?

Comment: I've used mine on convection mode for several years without a problem, then one day there was an almighty cracking sound and it broke (luckily into big pieces with no sharp shards). Never read the manual and I don't have it now, but I would next time.

Answer (score 4):

Assuming you do not have access to the instruction manual, and/or the manual does not specify whether it is safe to use the glass in convection/grill mode, I would assume not.

Are there any labels and/or writing embossed on the glass?

As I described in [this similar question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/questions/18524/are-glass-jars-from-the-supermarket-oven-safe/18541#18541), "regular" soda-lime glass is not heat safe.  Given that the glass was obviously designed for a microwave, it is probably tempered glass, so it can withstand some amount of heat.  Therefore, I would treat it like a Pyrex baking dish and not heat it to over 500°F.  Your microwave's convection mode likely does not get that hot, so you are *probably* fine with that, but no guarantees.  I would *not* use the tray in grill mode because even Pyrex is not broiler-safe.

Comment: Old-style Pyrex or new-style Pyrex?

Answer (score 3):

Microwave uses radio waves extremely short wave radio waves. Heat is hot it will break glass. The answer was embossed on the glass "for microwave use only". Just because it came with the microwave doesn't mean you can use it in the microwave.

Comment: "Heat is hot" - love it :)

Answer (score 2):

I have had a combination oven for many years and use the glass turntable for microwave and oven cooking and never had any problems. I do not use the grill so cannot comment on that.

Answer (score 1):

The microwave's turntable glass plate can be used in all the modes, convection, grill, microwave...   as well as in all combination modes.
It won't get damaged.
Be sure you clean it every time after use.

Comment: Do you have evidence, citation, or reasoning to support this answer?

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Usually the owners manual suffices as the "citation" :-)

Comment: @TFD ?????  There is no such reference here.

Comment: @SAJ14SAJ Anyone whom owns a microwave has a manual with it. The manual will say what to do! There is no one answer

Comment: @TFD The OP said their manual was vague on the subject...

Comment: Anybody who owns a microwave will have discarded the manual :)

Answer (score 1):

I used it in convection mode for 2 min at 200C and it cracked into 4 pieces!

Answer (score 1):

The glass plate in my Tesco MC2514 convection microwave oven broke the first time I tried using combination (microwave plus convection) cooking.  Tesco were very robust when I tried to get a replacement under warranty.  They did eventually send a replacement plate, but of the same material.  I am not confident enough to use the combination feature again with the new plate as I think it may well break again.

Answer (score 1):

The owner's manual for my RV microwave/convection oven says: "the glass tray and turntable ring assembly must always be used when cooking".

Answer (score 0):

I always have used it with microwave and convection cooking but recently pre-heated the convection to 220C (celcius) and had it going for 20 minutes.... smashed/cracked into several pieces. We’re yet to replace it but now I’d only use it to maybe 180C or 190C since that never seemed to be a problem.

Answer (score -1):

In my own experience I do not have any problems using my glass turntable in convection mode. I would suggest as others do here, clean the turntable after each use.

Comment: Hello Roy Evans and welcome! Unfortunately your answer does not give any information that has not already been given in other answers. Also, we prefer more detailed answers. As you are a new user, it may benefit you to visit our Tour and Help pages. Both can be found under the 'help' dropdown at the top of the page.